How to pass a double pointer as a const double pointer argument
How to pass a non constant double pointer as constant parameter to another function ?
My code:
#include <iostream>
    
void food(const char** begin, const char** end) {
    
}
    
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    food(argv, argv + argc);    
}

The error I get:
<source>: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
<source>:8:10: error: invalid conversion from 'char**' to 'const char**' [-fpermissive]
    8 |     food(argv, argv + argc);
      |          ^~~~
      |          |
      |          char**
<source>:3:24: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void food(const char**, const char**)'
    3 | void food(const char** begin, const char** end) {
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
<source>:8:21: error: invalid conversion from 'char**' to 'const char**' [-fpermissive]
    8 |     food(argv, argv + argc);
      |                ~~~~~^~~~~~
      |                     |
      |                     char**
<source>:3:44: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'void food(const char**, const char**)'
    3 | void food(const char** begin, const char** end) {
      |      


I would really recommend that you do a quick transformation of argv into a std::vector<std::string>. That will likely make your life much easier. Unless you need to work with a C API, in which case you can't convert the strings to be constant like that.

And what is supposed to be constant? There's a difference between const char**, char* const* and char** const.

@Someprogrammerdude I did give a thought about that. But just want to learn

You can't, as it's not safe. Consider const int x = 1; void f(const int** p) { *p = &x; } int main() { int* p = nullptr; f(&p); *p = 2; }, which would write to a const object.

This question is similar to: Why isn't it legal to convert "pointer to pointer to non-const" to a "pointer to pointer to const". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In C++ and C we are allowed to assign a type* to a const type*. This isn't the case here however - the problem in this case is that the const qualifier of the function parameter doesn't belong with the pointer-to-pointer but with the "pointer-to-pointed-at data".
Also argv is strictly speaking pointing at read/write memory, although writing to it is questionable practice.
We can get around this by adding pointers on the caller side:
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const char* begin = *argv;
    const char* end   = *(argv + argc);
    food(&begin, &end);    
}

Here *argv gives a char* to the data and we may assign that to a read-only const char*. And then pass a pointer to that one instead.

if I change the function food parameter types to const char* const* it works, which basically means cannot modify the list of pointers (char*) and also the data those pointers point to, if I'm correct. Do you think it makes sense?

@Harry Not really. Why would your function modify a list of pointers? It makes more sense to protect against modification of the argv data. We are actually allowed to modify that data, but since we can't resize it and since modifying it would destroy the original command line parameters, doing so is pretty senseless.

if a function accepts double pointer for eg. int** dp, then it can make the original single pointer int* sp point to something else and can also modify the data the original single pointer points to right? if that is the case, then I don't want these things to happen.

@Harry Then don't implement a function which does really strange things for really strange reasons...

In order to prevent such things, as a precautionary measure I thought to make parameters immutable using const. So, is this syntax const int* const* correct?

@Harry There's different levels of this: self-documenting code with const correctness = good. Protecting against accidental bugs writing to data that shouldn't be written to = good. Trying to protect the programmer from themselves = bad. If the programmer simply doesn't know wth they are doing, then no coding style in the world is going to salvage that situation. Additionally, while trying to come up with some obscure way to protect the programmer from themselves, the program might turns less readable and less maintainable to programmers who actually know what they are doing.

The other answers explain your immediate issue.
Here I would like to demostrate an alternative (already mentioned in a comment above):
Since you are using C++, transform the argc+argv (which are actually a legacy from C) to a C++ std::vector of std::strings.
Using standard containers and strings is much more idiomatic in C++ than using plain C arrays and C char arrays.
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void food(std::vector<std::string> const & args) {
    // Print args:
    for (auto const& arg : args) {
        std::cout << arg << "\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Build a `std::vector<std::string>`:
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv+argc);

    // Call `food`:
    food(args);
}

Live demo

@Lundin std::array requires that the size will be known at compile time.

Ah, I keep forgetting that C++ doesn't support VLA...

solution 1: make main take a const char** (note: may not be possible when main is hijacked, as done by SDL).
void food(const char** begin, const char** end) {

}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    food(argv, argv + argc);    
}

solution 2: create another const char* inside main that you can modify.
void food(const char** begin, const char** end) {

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const char* begin = *argv;
    const char* end = *(argv + argc);
    food(&begin, &end);    
}

Your original code cannot compile because inside food i could set *begin to a const char* stored in read-only memory, then in your main you will have a char* pointing to a const char which won't be correct.
creating a new begin and end that are already const char* avoids this issue, as any changes to them won't invalidate argv.
